# warzone fullscreen setting problem

Tags: 13.10

I changed the settings in Warzone 2100 from windowed mode to full screen and now when i try to run warzone 2100 it will not run. how can I change the settings out side of the game to fix this problem.

im using ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

To get the game to start in full screen, just run it once from shell by adding the argument --fullscreen:

```
$ warzone2100 --fullscreen
```

Once you run it that way, it will always run on full screen.